# Процессы в Linux

Tags: linux, shell

Нужно вывести процессы определенного пользователя

*ps -aux|grep ^'Пользователь'*

Пишет ,что не найдено

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще говоря, плохая практика использовать `grep` там где без него можно обойтись:

```
ps -u username
```

Также в зависимости от определения, что именно такое «процессы определённого пользователя» можно использовать `-U` вместо `-u`. (Смотри `man 1 ps` и `man 7 credentials` по поводу разницы реального и эффективного UID'а)

Answer (score 1):

Проверил, работает:

```
ps aux | grep ^username
```

Comment: а если юзернэйм 9+ символов?

Comment: Если юзернейм 9+ символов и эти первые 9 символов совпадают с другим пользователем, то такое решение не подойдёт. Маска поиска должна совпадать с тем что выводит ps aux

Comment: если юзернэйм будет 9+ символов, то в выводе `ps` это будет выглядеть как 7 первых символов и знак `+`. Например юзер `elasticsearch` превращается в `elastic+`. Так что шаблон поиска сокращается до первых 7-ми символов. А шаблон из 9-ти символов вообще не имеет смысла.

Comment: Спасибо всем, все заработала, и да и тот и тот метод правильный